# How to Make Python List Mutable as Its Slice is being changed

Tags: python, list, mutable

Python's slice operation creates a copy of a specified portion a list. How do I pass a slice of a parent list so that when this slice changes, the corresponding portion of the parent list changes with it?

```
def modify(input):
    input[0] = 4
    input[1] = 5
    input[2] = 6


list = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
modify(list[3:6])
print("Woud like to have: [1,2,3,4,5,6]")
print("But I got: "  + str(list))
```

Output:

Would like to have: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
But I got: `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`

Comment: You can't do that using regular Python lists.  You could instead pass the list and indices separately (e.g., `modify(list, 3, 6)`) and have `modify` use them to modify the list.

Comment: @thefourtheye: That doesn't make sense, since his goal is mutate the object.

Comment: Just use a slice assignment: `li=[1,2,3,1,2,3]` then `li[3:6]=[4,5,6]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with numpy if using numpy is an option:

```
import  numpy as np


def modify(input):
    input[0] = 4
    input[1] = 5
    input[2] = 6


arr = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3])
modify(arr[3:6])
print("Would like to have: [1,2,3,4,5,6]")
print("But I got: "  + str(arr))

Would like to have: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
But I got: [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Using [basic indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) always returns a [view](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-view) which is  *An array that does not own its data, but refers to another array’s data instead*

Depending on your use case and if you are using python3 maybe a [memeoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) with an [array.array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array) might work .

```
from array import array

arr = memoryview(array("l", [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]))

print(arr.tolist())

modify(arr[3:6])

print("Woud like to have: [1,2,3,4,5,6]")
print((arr.tolist()))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
Woud like to have: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```